# Mailing only works when executed manually, not scheduled

Tags: civimail, cron-job, scheduled-job

I am trying to executed a job to send out a mailing via CiviMail. This works when I do this manually, but fails when scheduled:

> permission check failed for Group/get call; insufficient permission: require access CiviCRM

What permission should I add to which user?

I am using Drupal 7 cron.

Comment: It looks like you've answered your own question here, which is great. This would fit better into the StackExchange format if you could post the solution as an answer. This makes it clearer for others which is the question and which is the answer.

Comment: Thanks for this. Did as you proposed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution:

- create a new user, add permissions:

  - View all contacts
  - Access CiviCRM
  - Access CiviMail
- go to admin/config/civicrm/civicrm-cron

See also: https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/setup/jobs/#choosing-a-cms-user

Answer (score 0):

You should give the permission to cron user.